# Compare two json objects and append unique items

Tags: javascript, node.js, unique

I have two JSON files - one fetched from the server (`data`), the other is local (`database`).

I'm trying to loop through the server json, compare it to the local json, and then append any new objects to the local file. This way when the script runs a second time, those new items have been appended and can be skipped.

Problem:

Currently when it runs after the initial time, because it checks `a-a, a-b, a-c, b-a, b-b, b-c...` it will skip the initial results, but then add in the other options.

The js Im using:

```js
let additions = [];
data.forEach(item1 => {
  database.filter(item2 => {
    if( !(item1.value === item2.value && item1.country === item2.country) ) {
      additions.push(item1)
    }
  })
});
```

Example / expectations:

```js
data = [
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" },
  { value: "asdfg", country: "CA" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "GB" }
] 

database = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" }
]
```

Then after the looping and checking, it would result in the following (initial run):

```js
output = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" },
  { value: "asdfg", country: "CA" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "GB" }
]
```

When I run the loop the next time, if the data has changed:

```js
data = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "wsxcd", country: "AU" },
  { value: "rfvbg", country: "NZ" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "FR" }
]
```

I am expecting this:

```js
output = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" },
  { value: "asdfg", country: "CA" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "GB" },
  { value: "wsxcd", country: "AU" },
  { value: "rfvbg", country: "NZ" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "FR" }
]
```

But I am receiving this:

```js
output = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" },
  { value: "asdfg", country: "CA" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "GB" },
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "wsxcd", country: "AU" },
  { value: "wsxcd", country: "AU" },
  { value: "wsxcd", country: "AU" },
  { value: "rfvbg", country: "NZ" },
  { value: "rfvbg", country: "NZ" },
  { value: "rfvbg", country: "NZ" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "FR" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "FR" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "FR" }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to figure it out so that it will append the items only unique, and not for item to item.

Comment: one lazy hack to finish this quickly is to use `Set`

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar That won't work since objects containing the same values still have separate identities. E.g. `new Set([{foo: 'bar'}, {foo: 'bar'}, 1, 1])` will yield a set with `{foo: 'bar'}` *twice* and, as expected, a single 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to get unique value based on `value` and `country` in an object accumulator. Then get all values from these object using `Object.values()`.

```js
const localData = [ { value: "qwert", country: "US" }, { value: "asdfg", country: "CA" }, { value: "zxcvb", country: "GB" }],
      database = [{ value: "poiuy", country: "CA" }, { value: "qwert", country: "US" }],
      getUnique = (arr1, arr2) => Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((r,o) => {
        const key = `${o.value}_${o.country}`;
        r[key] ??= o;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(getUnique(localData, database));
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it seems to work in the snippet but not in nodejs. I'm getting an error at `??=`. I tried searching for it to see what it was but can't find anything..

Comment: You can use `r[key] = r[key] || o` instead of `r[key] ??= o;`. `??` is the Nullish Coalescing operator.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the the easiest, but not the fastest way is simply merge arrays then filter unique values.

```js
let data = [
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" },
  { value: "asdfg", country: "CA" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "GB" }
] 

let database = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "qwert", country: "US" }
]

const getUniqueUnion = (data1, data2) => {
  return [...data1, ...data2].reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const match = acc.find((el) => {
      return el.country === cur.country && el.value === cur.value;
    });
    
    if (!match) {
      acc.push(cur);
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const result = getUniqueUnion(data, database);
console.log(result);

/*
  [
  {
    "value": "qwert",
    "country": "US"
  },
  {
    "value": "asdfg",
    "country": "CA"
  },
  {
    "value": "zxcvb",
    "country": "GB"
  },
  {
    "value": "poiuy",
    "country": "CA"
  }
]
*/

data = [
  { value: "poiuy", country: "CA" },
  { value: "wsxcd", country: "AU" },
  { value: "rfvbg", country: "NZ" },
  { value: "zxcvb", country: "FR" }
];

const result2 = getUniqueUnion(data, database);

console.log(result2);

/*
  [
  {
    "value": "poiuy",
    "country": "CA"
  },
  {
    "value": "wsxcd",
    "country": "AU"
  },
  {
    "value": "rfvbg",
    "country": "NZ"
  },
  {
    "value": "zxcvb",
    "country": "FR"
  },
  {
    "value": "qwert",
    "country": "US"
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group the `database` array by country, yielding a map from countries to sets of values. Using hash maps and sets will avoid duplicates.

To group do:

```js
let reducer = (acc, curr) => {
  let {country, value} = curr;

  if (acc.hasOwnProperty(country)) {
    acc[country].add(value);
  } else {
    acc[country] = new Set([value]);
  }

  return acc;
};
let groupedDatabase = database.reduce(reducer, {});
```

Then you loop over your `data` and just assign each entry to `groupedDatabase`. We can use the same reducer for that:

```js
let intermediateResult = data.reduce(reducer, groupedDatabase);
```

Every time `data` changes, update `intermediateResult`:

```js
intermediateResult = data.reduce(reducer, groupedDatabase);
```

Lastly, turn your grouped data back into an array:

```js
let output = Object.keys(intermediateResult).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let entries = Array.from(intermediateResult[curr]).map(value => {
    return {country: curr, value}
   });

  acc.push(...entries);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

This is assuming that you wanted to skip seen records only to avoid duplicates, not for performance reasons.

Sidenote:
The `reducer` mutates the passed initial value, such as `groupedDatabase`. This powers your ability to update `intermediateResult` using the exact same function invocation (the part `data.reduce(reducer, groupedDatabase);`). Due to mutation, be sure to use `groupedDatabase` only in this context. If you end up wanting to use it somewhere else (though I don't think you will since I introduced it only for this purpose), copy it first using `let copiedGroupedDatabase = Object.assign({}, groupedDatabase)`, or else you may be surprised when its value changes from under you.